# c++ lifetieme extension with different parentheses

Tags: c++, lifetime, temporary-objects

I'm trying to understand lifetime extension guarantees in C++. Can someone explain why the usage of different types of parentheses below yields differing results in terms of when the temporary object destructor is invoked?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct X  {
    X() { 
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ <<"\n";
    }
    ~X() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ <<"\n";
    }
};

struct Y {
    X &&y;
};
int main() { 
    Y y1(X{});    
    std::cout << "Here1\n";
    Y y2{X{}};
    std::cout << "Here2\n";
}
```

Output

```
X::X()
X::~X()
Here1
X::X()
Here2
X::~X()
```

Answer (score 18):

Since [C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary):

> There are following exceptions to this lifetime rule:
>
> - ...
> - a temporary bound to a reference in a reference element of an
>   aggregate initialized using direct-initialization syntax (parentheses)
>   exists until the end of the full expression containing the
>   initializer, as opposed to list-initialization syntax {braces}.
>
>   ```
>   struct A
>   {
>       int&& r;
>   };
>
>   A a1{7}; // OK, lifetime is extended
>   A a2(7); // well-formed, but dangling reference
>   ```

That means for `Y y2{X{}};`, the lifetime of temporary will be extended as `y2` (and its member); while for `Y y1(X{});` it won't, the temporary will be destroyed after full expression immediately.

Comment: I have been a C++ programmer for nearly 15 years now, and I cannot fully explain why there are so many initialization syntaxes with extremely subtle differences. What even.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo   Even people working with C++ longer than 15 years struggle with understanding the differences.   The reasons are largely historical, given that the language has evolved while retaining backward compatibility.  Some syntax/semantics are retained from C, some others from early C++ standards (and preceding draft standards). C++11 introduced syntax/semantics to help address frustrations (e.g. the most vexing parse) and also to better support new language features (such as rvalue references, etc). C++17 and later tweaked further ...

Comment: Well, yet another reason why braced initialization should be preferred over others.